# Returning an empty string in C++ using getcwd()

Tags: c++, string

I've a question on how to properly return an empty string in C++, see the code`enter code here` below:

```
string Options::getCwd()
{
    const char *buffer = getcwd(NULL, 0);
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        buffer = "";
    }
    string base(buffer);
    base += '/';

    return base;
}
```

The problem is that if getcwd() fails the returned buffer pointer is NULL, and setting buffer to the empty string solves that. However, I would like to return the empty string in base itself. The current code returns base="/" due to the concatenation of base with the empty string in buffer. Additionally attempting to free() buffer makes the compiler complain since strings in C++ has to be declared const.

Any other ideas on how to solve this in a better way?

Comment: String *literals* in C++ decay to `const char*`. There's nothing about C++ that says you have to store any `char*` in a `const char*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that:

```
if (buffer == NULL)
{
    return "";
}
```

The empty string literal will get implicitly converted into an empty std::string which will then get returned.

However you also have other problems, e.g. that `getcwd` expects a valid buffer as an input and not `NULL` (edited: clarification at the bottom).

The following total code should should work:

```
string Options::getCwd()
{
    char buffer[1024]; // Or optionally PATH_MAX
    char *result = getcwd(buffer, 1024);
    if (result == NULL)
    {
        // Optionally do something with errno here
        return "";
    }

    string base(buffer);
    base += '/';
    return base;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, it seems that is indeed possibly to pass `NULL` to `getcwd` and let it allocate the buffer. In that case call `free(result)` after `base` has been constructed.  I wouldn't recommend the approach since the dynamic allocation is not needed here.

Comment: I edited the answer and added some clarifications around that. Wasn't initially aware that `getcwd(NULL)` is legal with some posix extension.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep the NULL,0 arguments to getcwd() in my solution since you never know how long a directory path can become. Additionally, the original code use PATH_MAX, which is not portable since it is not defined on all OSes. Rewriting that function was the main purpose of this. (and the original code did not check return value of the getcwd() call)